# How to augment data in a Tensorflow Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-augmentation

For a set of images, I was confused if the term Data Augmentation meant to transform the current dataset (e.g. crop/flip/rotate/...) or if it meant to increase the amount of data by adding the cropped/flipped/rotated images to the initial dataset. As far as I understand, from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677788/data-augmentation-in-pytorch) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285018/data-augmentation-factor-in-training-a-cnn), it means both. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

So, using Tensorflow Dataset, I want to achieve the second one: augmenting the amount of data.

I'm using the ImageNet data from TFDS (trainning set is not available):

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
ds = tfds.load('imagenet_a', split='test', as_supervised=True)
```

And I want to flip the images:

```
def transform(image, label):
    image = tf.image.flip_left_right(image)
    return image, label
```

It works well if I apply the transformation directly to the dataset. But it doesn't increase the amount of data:

```
ds = ds.map(transform)
```

So, I tried to create a second dataset and concatenate both:

```
ds0 = ds.map(transform)
ds = ds.concatenate(ds0)
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Two datasets to concatenate have different types (tf.uint8, tf.int64) and (tf.float32, tf.int64)
```

Is it the way to do to concatenate two datasets to increase a training set?
Or how to do it correctly? (or how to fix my error)

*I'm aware of [ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator), but it doesn't contain the transformation I want*

Comment: I dont know but maybe [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-augmentate-data-using-keras-38d84bd1c80c) can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As the error clearly says, the two datasets should be having the same data types, you can achieve this using `tf.cast` but this is a bit hectic process for a large dataset.

You can also merge datasets using [tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/sample_from_datasets)

Below is the code with the illustration.

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, array_to_img
ds , info = tfds.load('imagenet_a', split='test', as_supervised=True,with_info=True)
```

**Original sample images:**

```
vis = tfds.visualization.show_examples(ds, info)
```

[image]

I'm taking 10 images for testing and flip those 10 images randomly with `map()` function to create a new dataset.

```
ds1 = ds.take(10)
ds2 = ds1.map(lambda image, label: (tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image), label))
#Merging both the datasets

new_ds = tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets([ds1,ds2])
print(len(list(new_ds))) # Which returns 20, 10 original plus 10 randomly filpped images. 

f, axarr = plt.subplots(5,4,figsize=(15, 15))

ix = 0
i = 0
count = 0
k = 0

for images, labels in new_ds:
  crop_img = array_to_img(images)
  axarr[i,ix].imshow(crop_img)
  ix=ix+1
  count = count + 1
  if count == 4:
     i = i + 1
     count = 0
     ix = 0
```

**Merged Dataset:**

You can see the merged data with original images and randomly flipped images.
[image]